# Can we use discriminator as many-to-one relationship in Table per class Hierarchy in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, database-design, hibernate-mapping

I have created `Device` Table in my application using hibernate. Every `Device` object contains 3 types of objects like `SADevicede`,`TXDeviceType`,`RxDeviceType`. 
(ie) Device is having list of SADeviceType,TXDeviceType,RxDeviceType

My goal is to genearte alarms for every SADevicetype, TXDeviceType and RxDeviceType with user defined restriction. It means that **Device A's** SADeviceType only should generate for Major error.**Device A's** TXDeviceType should generate only for Minor errors.  **Device B's** SADeviceType,TXDeviceType  should generate alarm for Major and Minor error.

I would like to use **Table Per class hierarchy** in this. For example I would like to create AlarmRestrictionDetail class and that sub classes are SAAlarmDetail, TXAlarmDetail and RxAlarmDetail . If I am going to create this by using hibernate, how will it handle if discriminator as many-to-one relation ship in Table per class Hierarchy
and how can generate three foreign keys at one discriminator column?

If it's not good idea, does any one help me that which kind of table structure is best when I am using hibernate ?

The reference code is below

```
  public class Device {
        private Integer id;
        private List<SADevicetype> saDeviceTypeList;
        private List<RxDeviceType> rxDeviceTypeList;
        private List<TXDeviceType> txDeviceTypeList;
  }

  public class AlarmRestrictionDetail {
    public Integer id;
    public String alarmName;
    public String severity;
  }

  public class SAAlarmDetail extends AlarmRestrictionDetail{

    // device type is a discriminator column 
    public SADevicetype deviceType;
  }

  public class  TXAlarmDetail extends AlarmRestrictionDetail {

    // device type is a discriminator column 
    public TXDeviceType deviceType;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `One Table Per class hierarchy` approach, If you need to have a the value of discriminator in your code, you may use a `read-only` property in the mapping.

```
public enum Devicetype {SADevicetype("SA") ,TXDeviceType("TX")  ,...}
public class AlarmRestrictionDetail {
    public Integer id;
    public String alarmName;
    public String severity;
    public Devicetype deviceType;
  }

 <class name="AlarmRestrictionDetail " table="AlarmRestrictionDetailTable">
    <id name="ID" column="id"/>    
    <property name="alarmName" column="severity" length="50"></property>
    <property name="severity" column="severity" length="50"></property>

    <discriminator column="discriminator_column" type="string"/>
    <property name="devicetype"  column="discriminator_column" access="readonly"/>

    <subclass name="SAAlarmDetail " discriminator-value="SA">
    <!-- ETC-->
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="TXAlarmDetail" discriminator-value="TX">
    <!-- ETC-->
    </subclass>       
  </class>
```